# ¿Es posible saber la cantidad de Registros en un ResultSet? Java

Tags: java

Tengo una pequeña inquietud sobre el `ResultSet` en Java, mi pregunta es

¿Podemos saber la cantidad de registros que tienen estos mismos al momento de terminar una consulta?

deseo obtener este dato para poder realizar una acción con esta cantidad de registros.

Hasta ahora lo que he investigado es que con `getMetaData()` podría obtener este numero, pero, hasta ahora sólo he podido extraer es el la cantidad de columnas que trae la consulta.

La otra solución que he pensado es realizar una consulta antes de la que trae los datos para contar el numero de registros con `COUNT()`, pero, no sé quería saber antes si es posible esto que planteo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No hay una manera AUN de poder saber el total. Pero si ya estas manejando la data y necesitas saber el total de esta, puedes hacer algo asi :

```
int total = 0;
while (result.next()){
   //Obtienes la data que necesitas...
   total++;
}
System.out.println("El total de registros es : "+total);
```

Tambien, lo que puedes hacer es utilizar el metodo `last()`, puedes verificar si el elemento que estas recorriendo actualmente es el ultimo entonces quedaria asi :

```
try {
    boolean ultimo = result.last();
    int total = 0;
    if (ultimo) { 
        total = result.getRow();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[getRow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow%28%29) devuelve un dato de tipo int y es el número de la fila actual, por lo tanto si tuvieras por ejemplo 10 resultados, va a caer el `last()` en el 10 y asi sabrias el total de resultados.

> int getRow() throws SQLException
>   Recupera el número de la fila actual. La primera fila es el numero 1, la segunda el 2 y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: Antes de recuperar los datos, no hay forma alguna de saber cuánta cantidad de registros trae, verdad? tocaría realizar 2 ciclos con 2 consultas?

Comment: No hay ningun metodo que te entregue el total de datos

Comment: Hmmmm tendría que hacer entonces un COUNT previo y tomar la cantidad de datos que este me trae. Crees que realizar esto me pueda afectar un poco? hablo de 2 consultas a la vez

Comment: Te deje otra opcion en mi respuesta @Salth95

Comment: No creo que te afecte, pero no es lo más optimo. Lamentablemente aun no existe la función que te devuelva la cantidad total de registros obtenidos. Pero puedes manipular la data y contar o bien, utilizar la segunda solucion que te di.

Comment: Gracias, @sioesi y lo imagine, pensaba que hacer eso podría afectar el aplicativo en cuestión de rendimiento. Me basaré en lo que me diste para mirar qué podré hacer :)

Comment: Un saludo! y cualquier cosa no dudes en dejar un comentario aqui :D @Salth95

Comment: Hay forma de saberlo, ResultSetMetadata, Revisa la respuesta de Nicolás.

Answer (score 4):

La clase `ResultSet` aún no nos proporciona una manera directa de extraer el número registros que tiene el mismo y con `ResultSetMetaData` lo que podemos extraer es el número de columnas que contiene nuestra consulta.
La manera más práctica que encontré de realizar esta tarea es la siguiente:

```
try {
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("CONSULTA");
     int cantFilas = 0;
     int cantColumnas = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();//sacamos la cantidad de columnas
     if(rs.last()){//Nos posicionamos al final
          cantFilas = rs.getRow();//sacamos la cantidad de filas/registros
          rs.beforeFirst();//nos posicionamos antes del inicio (como viene por defecto)
     }   

     while (rs.next()) {
     //VOLCAR LOS DATOS
     }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Lo que conseguimos con el código es sacar el número de filas, columnas y también continuar con nuestra variable `ResultSet` como viene por defecto. Podríamos entonces hacer lo siguiente:

1.Crear una matriz con las filas y columnas:

```
Object[][] matriz = new Object [cantFilas][cantColumnas]<br>
```

2.Dentro del `while` volcar los datos que contiene nuestra variable `ResultSet` en la matriz creada.

Espero que le ayude a alguien, saludos.

Comment: Esta debería de ser la respuesta aceptada... por lo mientras +1 de mi parte :)

Answer (score 2):

Otra forma de hacerlo sería mover el cursor al final con `last()` y luego obtener el `getRow()` que devuelve el número de fila actual.*(inicia en 1)*

```
if (rs.last()) 
   System.out.println("Cantidad de Registros : "  + rs.getRow());
else
   System.out.println("No Hay Registros ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que deseas es saber el numero de registros que obtuviste de tu consulta result set puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
int count = 0;

while (rs.next()) {
    ++count;
}

if (count != 0) {
    System.out.println("Existen " + count.toString() + " registros.");
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tras investigar por mi cuenta yo utilizo la sentencia Count para contar los registros que hay en una tabla. Si lo que quiero saber lo registros que tiene una consulta simplemente tengo que moficar los campos y añadir alguna condición a los Where.

```
try {
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/agruhoc","root","");
        //Sql
        Statement consulta= conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet cantidad = consulta.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS CANTIDAD FROM tabla_nombre");
        if(cantidad.next()){

            System.out.println(cantidad.getString("CANTIDAD"));

        }else{
            System.out.println("Ningun resultado encontrado");
        }       

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La manera en la que obtengo la cantidad de rows de un ResultSet es la siguiente:

```
try {
    // Obtenemos el resultado de nuestra query
    ResultSet resultado = ps.executeQuery();
    // Declaramos la variable que almacenara la cantidad de rows
    int cantidadRows;

    // Vamos al ultimo row del ResultSet con el metodo last()
    resultado.last();
    // Obtenemos el numero de row con el metodo getRow() el cual es el numero total de rows por ser el ultimo
    cantidadRows = resultado.getRow();

    // Por ultimo lo que hacemos es volver al primer row de nuestro ResultSet con el metodo beforeFirst(), esto ultimo por si necesitas usar los resultados de la query
    resultado.beforeFirst();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Espero que esta info te sea util, saludos

Comment: Está muy bien la respuesta, pero se diferencia en algo a las respuestas ya publicadas?